# Conditional renaming of files using Python

Tags: python-3.x, file-rename

First of, I'm a complete newbie in the Python language but I can see that I can do whatever I want with Python. Definitely going to learn more!

For now I'm looking to build a script that can rename series of .tif files that I generated from a microscope based on a predefined layout in x & y. For instance, if I have a series of .tifs that are generated from a 7 x 13 scan (in x & y resp.) , so a total of 91 views. This grid is acquired in a snake by rows manner. The files generated are now named as `generic_name_v01z0001` where the v01 relates to the first view. But these are not representative of the imaged grid, they're just sequentially numbered. For downstream processing I would like to have them named as `generic_name_[yy x xx]_z`, so the v01 .tif would be 00 x 00 and the v91 .tif would be 13 x 07.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to approach this?

Edit: Z0001 is a sequentially going up to the end of v01. So the last .tif in v01 would be `generic_name_v01_z0238` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea.  It wasn't clear which x/y coordinate would increase first as you go from 1-91 and 00x00 to 13x07 is too many locations (14x8) so I went 00x00 to 12x06.  You may want to adjust the numbering.

Once the `print` shows the command you want, comment it out and uncomment the `os.rename`:

```py
import os

for i in range(1,92):
    src = f'generic_name_v{i:02}z0001.tif'
    x, y = divmod(i-1, 13)
    dst = f'generic_name_[{y:02} x {x:02}]_z.tif'
    print(f'os.rename({src!r}, {dst!r})')
    # os.rename(src, dst)
```

Output:

```
os.rename('generic_name_v01z0001.tif', 'generic_name_[00 x 00]_z.tif')
os.rename('generic_name_v02z0001.tif', 'generic_name_[01 x 00]_z.tif')
...
os.rename('generic_name_v90z0001.tif', 'generic_name_[11 x 06]_z.tif')
os.rename('generic_name_v91z0001.tif', 'generic_name_[12 x 06]_z.tif')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Indeed it would be (12x06) if I start at (00x00). One confounding factor that I forgot to mention (professional deformation), but z0001 is a counter that would need to go up until the next v{i:02}.

The output so far does indeed match what I'm looking for, so I have high hopes!